# If create a tag can I earn points?

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation

So if I create Tag in stack exchange, lets say the tag is very useful, and daily lot of questions coming under that tag, for example "javascript", will I earn any points or can I increase reputation based on the no of questions under that tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you will not earn points for a tag you created.

There *is* a [silver badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) to be earned:

> Taxonomist:  Created a tag used by 50 questions